# How to setup multiple manifest based on domain with Workbox

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a `react` app that I am deploying to a single domain

`https://app.*.com`

the * is basically the name of the domain, that can be multiple `app.A.com` `app.B.com`.

In firebase, we configured those domain to serve the hosting so no matter what URL you reach you will see the same content, but some stuff on the page will change based on the domain. There is basically a firebase function replacing the header before service the `index.html` that will write down `manifest.A.json` or `manifest.B.json` based on what domain the request is from.

I setup a `manifest.A.json` and a `manifest.B.json`, I register them the same way

`webpack.config.js`

```
      new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/service-worker.ts'),
        // this is the output of the plugin,
        // relative to webpack's output directory
        swDest: 'service-worker.js',
        // vendor currently is 4.21MB so limit set to 5MB
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 7 * 1024 * 1024,
      })
```

then in my `main.json`

```
  serviceWorkerRegistration.register({
    path: 'service-worker.js',
    onSuccess: () => pwaStore.setState((state) => ({ ...state, isReady: true })),
    onUpdate: () => pwaStore.setState((state) => ({ ...state, hasUpdate: true })),
  });
```

`service-worker.js`

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { setCacheNameDetails } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

import { environment } from '~anyx/app-core/env';

// ServiceWorkerGlobalScope is a type from the workbox-precaching module
declare const self: Window & ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

const version = process.env['NX_VERSION'] || '';
setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: environment.appName,
  suffix: version,
});

if (version === '') {
  Sentry.captureException(new Error('Encountered Empty Version Name!'));
}

// Tells the Service Worker to skip the waiting state and become active.
self.skipWaiting();

// Will make the Service Worker control the all clients right away
// (even if they're controlling other tabs or windows). Without this,
// we could be seeing different versions in different tabs or windows.
clientsClaim();

precacheAndRoute([...self.__WB_MANIFEST]);
```

Problem is, when I visit A.com, all is fine, but B.com return

> Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://B.com/') with script ('https://B.com/service-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

I am unsure why this issue happen only on B.com, maybe I have something more to configure for it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache and let's see what happens.
If you've previously registered a Service Worker with the same scope, it might be interfering with the new registration. Try clearing the browser cache or unregistering the old Service Worker.

You can obtain additional logs by configuring this in service-worker.js as follows.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('Service Worker installed');
  // Your code for installation...
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  console.log('Service Worker activated');
  // Your code for activation...
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log('Fetching:', event.request.url);
  // Your code for handling fetch events...
});
```